# Is this still valid すきはなんですか?

Tags: sentence, construction

People say that the correct way to ask "what do you like" is なにがすきですか but if I use すきはなんですか is that still consider grammatically correct? and will people raise an eyebrow at me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

好き is an adjective, not a noun, so 「好きは何ですか」 is incorrect. If you really want to use this order, you can insert もの ('things') and say 「好きなものは何ですか？」'What are the things you like?'

EDIT: Now that I've thought some more, I have heard 好き used as a noun, but it's always referred to the general concept of liking things, not specific things one likes. Thus 「好きは何ですか」would probably be taken as 'What is liking?' or 'What does it mean to like something?'